# TextView drawableStart wrap_content doesn't work well

Tags: android, textview, compound-drawables, android-wrap-content

I want to display a textview with a compound drawable which wraps the content - the shape and the text. Here is my code:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/text_category_name"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
android:drawableStart="@drawable/shape_circle"
android:drawablePadding="10dp"
android:padding="10dp"
android:textSize="16sp" />
```

drawableLeft works fine, it wraps the shape and and text, no problem. But drawableStart (and so I assume drawableEnd) seems to wrap the text, THEN add the image, and as such trim the text, so it looks like this:

[image]

I've tried removing the drawablePadding, padding, layout_marginStart - these don't have an effect on the text still being trimmed.

Is there a non-hacky way to fix this? I don't want to have to set a specific width, and I do want to use drawableStart and not drawableLeft if possible. I've had a look for existing answers, and all I can find so far is that it is a quirk of the RTL nature of drawableStart/End, but I can't see a clean solution.

Comment: show me complete `XML` code

Comment: that's my file, this is for use to display a spinner. Spinner is also set to wrap_content. It's used in an ArrayAdapter. What else do you need? I'm trying to keep question minimal, as guidelines, don't want to obfuscate question.

Comment: try to set **`android:drawableEnd="@drawable/shape_circle"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/shape_circle"`**

Comment: add my launcher icon to beginning and end - ok, why though?

Comment: @vin show your spinner's `xml` code

Comment: '<Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner_assessment_category"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />'

Comment: @VinNorman just for test case **drawableEnd=** and **drawableStart** is working when using wrap content

Comment: yeah i tried it, and as my launcher icon is even bigger, I just see even less of my text. It's a RTL thing, as drawableLeft and drawbleRight, it measures I think the drawable and text together, so wrap works... I think drawbleStart/End doesn't measure the drawable for wrap calculation